# Outputs ignored in cron jobs

Tags: php, cron, output

I've used cron to make my web application call every 10 minutes a PHP program.

I see in `/var/log/syslog` the following error: `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`.

As far as I understood, it's due to the fact that cron manages outputs only via mails or files: https://ubuntuplace.info/questions/258/cron-info-aucun-mta-installe-suppression-de-la-sortie-erreur

For architecture reasons, I want my periodic PHP program to be able to get (and use) the output of another PHP program.

What should I do ?

Comment: you can redirect it to a program using the | pipe or redirect to a file >/some.file

Comment: And then use written outputs via another program reading /some.file ?

Comment: Yes. > will only write STDOUT . If you need STDERR use 2> . And you can use 2>&1 to redirect STDERR to STDOUT some times it is use full.

Comment: It's quite heavy. Isn't there a solution which really permits to use PHP as usual ? I don't feel forced to use cron.

Comment: What do you mean? The operators are a OS level system. Normally anything output in a cron job is usually an uncontrolled error.  As a last resort cron sends an email to the user of the process runs under. what are you trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to update more than one DB table on a regular basis. Maybe there's another way than cron ?

Comment: cron is probably the most reliable way for you to call a process.  But you have to work with it. You have to put file full path to your program in cron. Then in the program you have to put fill file names in. Start with sending your output to a file  >/home/<user>/cronerr.txt 2>&1

Comment: Could I use one of the following schedulers https://www.maketecheasier.com/cron-alternatives-linux/ ? Do they have the same "problem" of lack of output management ?

Comment: They look interesting. But I guess they will have the same underlying conditions.  They will run as root. Then become the user to run it. The big thing to think about are the user permissions to edit files and write files. check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto  and https://crontab.guru/ to help scheduling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225257/discussion-between-zlotz-and-jason-k).